# How can I connect to an Oracle database from Ant using the tnsname?

Tags: oracle, ant, jdbc

I am looking for something similar to the Ant sql task but that will accept a JDBC url of the format:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS_NAME

One possible approach seems to be to write my own Ant task that uses an OracleDataSource to create the Connection, but is there a way to do this straight in Ant?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the responses so far guys. I hope it helps if I elaborate a bit more on the error I'm getting.

My Ant task looks as follows:

```
<target name="MyTarget" >
    <property name="oracle.net.tns_admin" value="/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0.1/NETWORK/ADMIN" />
    <property name="jdbc.driver" value="ojdbc5.jar" />
    <property name="jdbc.i18n.support" value="orai18n.jar" />
    <property name="jdbc.driver.class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <path id="sql.class.path">
        <pathelement location="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <pathelement location="${jdbc.i18n.support}" />
    </path>

    <sql driver="${jdbc.driver.class}" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@THE_TNS_NAME" userid="USER" password="PASSWORD" classpathref="sql.class.path" >
        <![CDATA[
        #SOME ARBITRARY SQL HERE
        ]]>
    </sql>
</target>
```

This fails with the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Unknown host specified

Replacing the url with "jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:INSTANCE" works fine, and I can also tnsping the tns name used above, so I know it's valid.

Comment: That should just work with the usual Ant sql task, shouldn't it? Is there a problem with using it that way?

Comment: It would be perfect if it just worked, but I must be doing something wrong. I have updated the question with my Ant script--is there a fault?

Comment: Are you connection with Oracle or MySQL ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was just working with this today and stumbled upon the missing piece.  The TNS location needs to be set as a system property as indicated here: [Oracle thin JDBC to TNS name](http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/2008/02/03/oracle-thin-jdbc-to-tns-name/)

> To establish an Oracle thin JDBC connection to a TNS alias (tnsname), 
>   make sure you pass the oracle.net.tns_admin system property to the JVM. 
>   Its value should be the directory in which your tnsnames.ora file is 
>   located. After that, you can just pass the TNS alias in place of the 
>   host name in the JDBC URL.
>
> E.g. if you simply try to connect to jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYDB, which 
>   is in your tnsnames.ora file, you’ll get an SQLException with a detail 
>   message of Io exception: Unknown host specified. If you fire up the JVM 
>   with a -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/oracle/10g/NETWORK/ADMIN, or use 
>   System.setProperty(String,String) after startup, the connection
>   will be established successfully.

After doing this I was able to successfully connect using the TNS alias alone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's been so long since I had this problem that I can barely remember the details, but your answer seems very promising, :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's NETWORK/ADMIN and not network/admin?

Unix filesystems are usually case sensitive - (assuming it's on Unix).

Comment: You're quite right, it is actually "network/admin". However, I have tried both and it made no difference. I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to pass the property to the sql task (when I call the java target, I use a 'sysproperty', but the sql task doesn't seem to support this...).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want a "thick" connection that uses tnsnames.ora and not the thin driver, then you can wrap a call to sqlplus in the xml file:

```
<target name="myTarget">
  <!-- login.sql should have sqlcode exit so failonerror will fail build -->
  <exec executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${userid}/${password}@${tnsalias}"/>
        <arg value="@myScript"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

... is the basic idea.

[where userid, password, and tnsalias are defined in your properties file]

This obviously means you'll have to have at least the Instant Client stack installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't now yet, what the exact problem is, I can only assume that this might help:

http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.com/2008/04/jdbc-thin-connection-using-tnsnamesora.html

Comment: This link has been very useful for me in the past, but in this particular case I am trying to connect from within Ant. Do I still need to specify the oracle.net.tns_admin system property? If so, how would I do that? I have updated my question with the way I am currently using it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would think so. You do it like this: <sysproperty key="test.property" value="blue" />
which I copied from here: http://ideoplex.com/id/372/setting-java-system-properties-with-ant